# How can C.dll expose variable to Python?

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, ctypes

I am trying to write a C main program into a dll, and Python will import everything (including all variables and functions) from this dll, and runs the function that is defined in dll. However, I intend to export not only the function but also the variables from DLL to Python. 
I understand how to expose functions to Python with DLL, but i'm not sure how to access variables from dll with Ctype in Python.

Let's take an example: 
if inside the header, we have #DEFINE MAXDEVNUMBER   4.
when I use ctype print mydll.MAXDENUMBER  it threw me an error. function 'MAXDENUM' not found

[image: Variables defined]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access preprocessor macros because they are not exported from a DLL.  You can only access exported C functions and global variables.

For example, **test.c**:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int b = 5;

__declspec(dllexport) int func(int a)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

> ```
> >>> from ctypes import *
> >>> dll = CDLL('test')
> >>> dll.func(1)
> 6
> >>> x=c_int.in_dll(dll,'b')  # access the global variable
> >>> x.value
> 5
> >>> x.value = 6              # change it
> >>> dll.func(1)
> 7
> ```

Comment: What about exposing an array? to Python?

Comment: Just use the right type. For example: `x = (c_int * 10).in_dll(dll,'b')` to access `int b[10]`.

Comment: Thanks Sir. You are the hero. Everything works now !!

Comment: Tolnen What about 2 dimensional array?

Comment: `(c_int * 10 * 5)` for `int b[5][10]`.  Note the indices are reversed.